# How to download file using PHP & JavsScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How can I use PHP to download a file from server or third party URL.

Also I want the exact event when the file is completely downloaded. So want to call some custom JS on that event.

#### Tried with pure JavaScript

I tried below snippet, but got blocked access error.

> Access to fetch at 'https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf' from origin 'http://localhost/test.php' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

**JS Code below**

```js
let fileurl = 'https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf';
  fetch(fileurl)
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = url;
    // the filename you want
    a.download = fileurl;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    alert('your file has downloaded!'); // or you know, something with better UX...
  })
  .catch(() => alert('oh no!'));
```

#### Tried with PHP + Ajax

In this case I noticed if I call this file with browser then it's now able to download file.
But here I cannot get the actual download complete event.
Also when I have called the PHP url using AJAX then got encoded string like below.

```
%PDF-1.7
%����
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-GB) /StructTreeRoot 291 0 R/Outlines 285 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 672 0 R/ViewerPreferences 673 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
```

**PHP Code below**

```php
$url = 'https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf';
$filename = basename($url);
$filetype = filetype($url);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
header("Content-type: " . $filetype); // act as image with right MIME type
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($url);
```

Please suggest what are the best possibility to achieve this. With no complex things. Also should work with all native browsers and devices.

Comment: w3.org doesn't allow you to download their files via CORS AJAX requests. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS to understand what CORS is and how it works. There's nothing you can do about that, if they don't permit it.

Comment: Best idea is probably to use your PHP code as a proxy and make the AJAX request to that script instead.

Comment: `when I have called the PHP url using AJAX then got encoded string like below`...did you use the exact same code as in your first example, except changing `fileurl` to have a different value? Because if so then you should get the same result.

Comment: w3.org  is just for an example I am trying for other urls.  Also don't want page reload.

Comment: Well ok but most sites will not enable CORS by default, so the proxy via PHP is likely to be needed the majority of the time.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson I got new idea on this I will try if succeed then will share here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After so many ways I have tried. Created and tested below code snippet and works fab.

File - **index.html**

```html
<a data-url="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" data-file-name="Dummy.pdf" id="downloadBtn">Downalod</a>
<script>
  let fileUrl = $('#downloadBtn').attr('data-url');
  let fileName = $('#downloadBtn').attr('data-file-name');
  fetch('download.php?url=' + fileUrl)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      // Create a Blob URL from the response data
      const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      // Create a download link
      const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
      downloadLink.href = blobUrl;
      downloadLink.download = fileName; // set the desired file name
      downloadLink.style.display = 'none';

      // Trigger a click event on the download link
      document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
      downloadLink.click();
      document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);

      // Revoke the Blob URL
      URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
</script>
```

File - **download.php**

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
  $url = $_GET['url'];
  $filename = basename($url);

  $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
  $contentType = $headers["Content-Type"];

  $filetype = filetype($url);
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
  header("Content-type: " . $contentType); // act as image with right MIME type
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile($url);
  exit;
}
```